# div visible false in server side using div class in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a div in  aspx page given below. I have a page that contains the desktop and mobile code and style. I want to show show hide div according to condition. using id (more than 50 div on page) this increase the code and id, using class that is provided above "desktop and "mobile" reduce the code.

```
<div class="desktop" runat="server">
            <p>this desktop version1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Mobile" runat="server">
            <p>this mobile version1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="desktop" runat="server">
            <p>this desktop version1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Mobile" runat="server">
            <p>this mobile version1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="desktop" runat="server">
            <p>this desktop version1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Mobile" runat="server">
            <p>this mobile version1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="desktop" runat="server">
            <p>this desktop version1</p>
        </div>
```

I want to show hide div using div class (not div id) in server side.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Finally i find solution of this, If any query regarding this please reply.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   string theClass;
   theClass = "desktop";
        var theControls = FindByClass(theClass);
        foreach (Control item in theControls)
        {
            //do something;
            if (item is WebControl)
            {
                ((WebControl)item).Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
               ((HtmlControl)item).Visible = false;
            }
        }

    }

    private IEnumerable FindByClass(string theClass)
    {
        Control[] allControls = FlattenHierachy(Page);


        var theControls = from n in allControls
                          where ((n is WebControl)
                          && ((WebControl)n).CssClass.Contains(theClass))
                          || (n is HtmlControl
                              && ((HtmlControl)n).Attributes.Count > 0
                              && ((HtmlControl)n).Attributes["class"] != null
                              && ((HtmlControl)n).Attributes["class"].IndexOf(theClass) > -1)
                          select n;
        return theControls;
    }

    public static Control[] FlattenHierachy(Control root)
    {
        List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
        list.Add(root);
        if (root.HasControls())
        {
            foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
            {
                list.AddRange(FlattenHierachy(control));
            }
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you do not want to use id?

Comment: This sounds like a case of css and media-queries, not server-side calculations. What would the different between the div-elements?

Comment: Either way.. split them apart into their own `div`s that group each type.. then show and hide them.

Comment: I have a page that contains the desktop and mobile code and style. I want to show show hide div according to condition. using id this increase the code and id, using class that is provided above "desktop and "mobile" reduce the code.

Comment: I want functionality visible false that is in server side.

Comment: Have you considered responsive design with css3 and media queries? This is natively supported in the browsers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, it's much better to use media-quires in your case.

But let's just stay with your question, ignoring the reason. You can find all controls recursively, and then hide them:

```
    private IEnumerable<HtmlGenericControl> FindControls(ControlCollection controls, string className)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            var c = control as HtmlGenericControl;
            if (c != null)
            {
                var classAttribute = c.Attributes["class"];
                if (classAttribute != null)
                    if (classAttribute.Equals(className))
                        yield return c;
            }
            if (control.HasControls())
                foreach (var subControl in FindControls(control.Controls, className))
                    yield return subControl;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var a = FindControls(Page.Controls, "Mobile").ToList();
        a.ForEach(p=>p.Visible = false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using jquery. Just Put your code inside Head tag

```
<head runat="server">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
function test() {
   if(condition)
   {
        $(".first").hide();
   }
   else
   {
        $(".first").show();
   }
}

</head>
```

Now you First Call this on any event like on button click. Then Put your condition to hide or show div inside 'if' block. This works fine for me.